# How do I investigate or fix random IO HDD & system freezes on linux?

Tags: ubuntu, io, freeze

My home desktop system is Ubuntu 18.04.1 with kernel regularly updated, currently 5.3.0. From time to time, mostly when browsing but not necessarily, the system becomes slow on IO:
- hdd LED constantly on
- system slow on all disk request. E.g. console login or `ls ~/` takes minutes
- system fast on other things (mouse moves, virtual console switching)
- iotop shows multiple apps 99% waiting for IO
- iostat shows high wrqm, low wrkb/s

after a few minutes the system goes into a complete freeze, I only can make a hard reboot

What can I do to investigate the problem better?
What scheduler would you recommend?
If it's a single app killing my hdd, is there a way to disallow it to do so?

*Update*:
The disk is HDD, i.e. a spinning disk. The apps showing IO waits are just all doing IO really. No swapping, there is enough memory. No relevant lines in syslog, I'll see /var/log/messages on the next occurrence

Comment: Which processes are showing high usage, what type of drive do you have (SSD, HDD), and do you see any relevant errors in /var/log/messages or syslog?

Comment: Immediate reaction is that something is using all of memory, and the system is paging in parts of executables as it is out of swap. I would run `top` rather than `iotop` and sort by memory usage rather than cpu usage to confirm this. Setting suitable ulimit values could prevent this, but where to set them depends on what is causing the problem.

Comment: @cutrightjm -- I've updated the top post

Comment: @icarus -- I've updated the top post

Answer (score 1):

Beside using tools like `top` or `glances`, your first bet is `journalctl`.

I had a similar problem and I started `journalctl -b -f` in a terminal and left it there. When the problem occurred, it displayed the message **kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: GPU HANG: ecode 9:1:0x00000000, hang on rcs0**, which turned out to be a [bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/issues/673) in kernel 5.3 and 5.4 at least.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also want to verify the health status of your disk. Some disks can keep retrying for quite a while when they fail to read a block. If the read will eventually succeed, there might not be any I/O errors reported. But if the disk keeps retrying for too long, the kernel may eventually time out the operation.

Something like `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` will produce a pretty comprehensive report. After the first part that just provides the manufacturer, model and other identification information for the disk, you'll want to see the following lines:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

If the result is anything other than `PASSED`, it's time to make sure your backups are in order. If you use your computer for anything important, I'd recommend replacing such failing disks ASAP, without waiting for them to completely die on you.

In most cases, there should also be a table of SMART attributes and their values. The values are represented in a scaled form: as long as each value is above a reported threshold value, the disk's internal diagnostics still think the disk is "good enough". There is also a separate *raw value* column, which may be interesting in case of attributes like "power on hours".

Depending on the SMART capabilities of the specific disk model, there could be also more detailed error logs and/or self-test results displayed.

If the disk seems good, you might want to try a different SATA cable. It seems that in recent years there have been some bad batches of SATA cables on the market.